# Access to shape functions in mboost

Tags: r, boosting

I am looking into the `mboost` package in `R` for creating GAM models. Below is code for creating a very simple GAM model with tree stumps on the `mtcars` data set.

```
library(mboost)

my_model = mboost(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp,
                  data = mtcars, 
                  baselearner = "btree", 
                  control = boost_control(mstop = 1000, nu = 0.1))

par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(my_model)
```

The resulting shape plots for the three functions $f_{cyl}, f_{disp}, f_{hp}$ look like this:
[image]

I can now use the model to predict new instances by calling `predict(mymodel, newdata)`. **However, is there a way to predict by using one of the shape functions at the time?** In practice, this means that I would like to call something like `predict(f_cyl, newdata)`, `predict(f_disp, newdata)` or `predict(f_hp, newdata)` where `f_cyl`, `f_disp` and `f_hp` are the shape functions that together make up the GAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use  `predict.mboost(object = my_model, newdata = mtcars, which = 1)`,  in order to get predictions only from shape function 1 (and `which = 2` to get predictions only from shape function 2, etc.).

Now these predictions can be stored in a data frame and can plotted in ggplot2, or used for other purposes.

Thanks to Dr. Benjamin Hofner for pointing this out to me!